# How to install Python MySQLdb without install MySQL Server

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I found mysqllib at http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/.

So can I install MySQLdb without installing MySQL Server?

Just copy mysqlib to `/usr/local/mysql`?

Could it be possible? And how to do that?

And which version will match my machine (I use OSX Lion)?

I want to use it to connect to a MySQL server on another machine for Django.

Thanks for help!

================================

Thing that I had try already

1. download http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/ 64-bit
2. extract to /usr/local/mysql
3. download MySQL-python-1.2.3
4. create symbolic link gcc-4.2 to gcc (because when it compile it run gcc-4.2 instead of gcc)
5. in MySQL-python-1.2.3 folder edit setup_posix.py 
   edit mysql_config.path = "/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config"
6. sudo python setup.py clean
7. edit _mysql.c every include mysqllib to proper path

example #include "mysql.h"  ===> #include "/usr/local/mysql/include/mysql.h"

1. sudo python setup.py build

and I found this error

```
Oats-MacBook:MySQL-python-1.2.3 Oat$ sudo python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7
copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7
creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/constants
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7
gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Dversion_info=(1,2,3,'final',0) -D__version__=1.2.3 -I/usr/local/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/_mysql.o
In file included from _mysql.c:36:
/usr/local/mysql/include/my_config.h:185:1: warning: "SIZEOF_LONG" redefined
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:9,
                 from pymemcompat.h:10,
                 from _mysql.c:29:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pymacconfig.h:54:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from _mysql.c:36:
/usr/local/mysql/include/my_config.h:205:1: warning: "SIZEOF_SIZE_T" redefined
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:9,
                 from pymemcompat.h:10,
                 from _mysql.c:29:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pymacconfig.h:56:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
gcc-4.2 -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -g build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/lib -lmysql -lpthread -o build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/_mysql.so
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/lib'
ld: library not found for -lmysql
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/lib'
ld: library not found for -lmysql
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//ccnEbgua.out (No such file or directory)
error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want try [PyMySQL](https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL) - it's a python implementation of MySql client. So you will not need to fiddle with binaries and admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to connect to a MySQL Server on another machine? If so then the easiest thing would be to install the libmysql package that comes with your (I presume) Linux distribution.

If however you're talking about the embedded version of MySQL (without a server anywhere) then you need to download the source for mysql-python, modify site.cfg to specify support for embedded rather than server and rebuild it.

Comment: I use OSX Lion 

and I want to connect to MySQL Server on another machine